# Unable to implement navigation drawer properly

Tags: android

I am using the sample code from the developer.android.com for navigation drawer. I am unable to know what exactly needs to be changed to start activities instead of images which now appear. So what parts do I need to delete so that I can make listviewitemclick to open activities?
I am working here

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
 switch(position){
 case 0:
 Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sampleopen.class); 
 startActivity(a);
 }
 }
```

The problem is that it opens the second activity first then when we press back it goes to first activity and there the drawer is implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());`
Here you define a listener - you need to provide your own instead of new DrawerItemClickListener() and there you'll be able to launch activities according to position received.

```
// set the on item click listener for the listview object
mNavigationListView.setOnItemClickListener(mOnNavigationItemClickListener);

// handle clicks here
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnNavigationItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            if (position == 0) then launch ACtivity #1
            //.... 
        }
    };
```

Comment: I can't see any drastic changes. You still have to provide your own OnItemClickListener;

Comment: Okay I will see that. Also the activity that is opening when the item is selected from navigation drawer opens new page instead of loading on same page as it does in G+. How can I do that? Are they using fragments?

Comment: They don't actually launch activities but rather swap fragments in the  content area. The basic idea is that in the layout there's a container(Framelayout) which can store different fragments. So, when you click on a navigation item you should replace the fragment.